# How do you re-display a JTree node?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using Java Swing v2 by Robinson & Vorobiev as a framework to understand JTree's. I have redone the source code from [https://www.manning.com/books/swing-second-edition][1] Chapter17/4 to include better encapsulating and information hiding. The **rename** EditorListener (**CellEditorListener**) had a bug in that java.io.File.rename() did not work but java.nio.Files.move() does. I then included checks for an existing directory and for a failure to move.

The issue is that in these two failures the only thing needed is to update the GUI so that the original value of the node is displayed. The node data does not change and does not need to be updated. The display area update I know how to do. But I do not know how to update only the displayed node. The only thing that seems to work is to replace the tree node with a new version of itself.

Code is below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    /** 
 *  Copyright 1999-2002 Matthew Robinson and Pavel Vorobiev. 
 *  All Rights Reserved. 
 * 
 *  =================================================== 
 *  This program contains code from the book "Swing" 
 *  2nd Edition by Matthew Robinson and Pavel Vorobiev 
 *  http://www.spindoczine.com/sbe 
 *  =================================================== 
 * 
 *  The above paragraph must be included in full, unmodified 
 *  and completely intact in the beginning of any source code 
 *  file that references, copies or uses (in any way, shape 
 *  or form) code contained in this file. 
 */ 

/*
   Source Code: https://www.manning.com/books/swing-second-edition Chapter17/4
*/

package ch17.v4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

/**
 *
 * @author Java Swing vrs. 2
 */

public class EditorListener implements CellEditorListener {
   protected Tree                  m_tree;
    protected DefaultTreeCellEditor m_editor;
    protected DefaultTreeModel      m_model;
    protected JTextField            m_display;

   public EditorListener( DefaultTreeCellEditor m_editor
                        , Tree              m_tree
                        , DefaultTreeModel  m_model
                        , JTextField        m_display) {
      this.m_editor  = m_editor;
      this.m_tree    = m_tree;
      this.m_model   = m_model;
      this.m_display = m_display;
   } // EditorListener()

   @Override
   public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
      if (m_tree.m_editingNode != null) {
         String newName = m_editor.getCellEditorValue().toString();
         File dir       = m_tree.m_editingNode.getFile();
         File newDir    = new File(dir.getParentFile(), newName);

         m_tree.m_editingNode = null;                                  // moved

  /******************************** New Code ********************************/
         if(newDir.exists()) {
            int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null                           // parent
                                                     , "Do you wnat to overwrite>"    // message 
                                                     , newName                        // title 
                                                     , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION      // optionType 
                                                     , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  // messageType 

            if (value == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
               update(dir);
               return;
            }
         }
         try {
            Path move = Files.move( dir.toPath()         // from
                                  , newDir.toPath()      // to
                                  , StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
          } catch (IOException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null                            // parent
                                         , "Unable to rename"              // message 
                                         , newName                         // title 
                                         , JOptionPane.OK_OPTION           // optionType 
                                         , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     // messageType 
             System.out.println( "[ERROR] Unable to rename " 
                               + dir.toString() + " "
                               + exception.getMessage());
             update(dir);
             return;
          }
  /**************************************************************************/

//         dir.renameTo(newDir);

         // Update tree
         update(newDir);
      }
   }

   private void update( File dir) {                           // correctly displays node
         TreePath path = m_tree.getSelectionPath(); 
         DefaultMutableTreeNode node = Tree.getTreeNode(path);
         IconData idata = new IconData( DirTree.ICON_FOLDER
                                      , DirTree.ICON_EXPANDEDFOLDER
                                      , new FileNode(dir));
         node.setUserObject(idata);
         m_model.nodeStructureChanged(node);
         m_display.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());

   } // void update( File dir)

   @Override
   public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
      m_tree.m_editingNode = null;
   }

   private void restoreName() {

   } // void restoreName()

} // class EditorListener implements CellEditorListener
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that and now that I have been corrected, will not again mention it.